# How to save unicode with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy

I've encountered such error:

```
File "/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 435, in do_execute
            cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
        exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 8410: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It happens when Im trying to save ORM object with assigned Python's `unicode` string. And as a result `dict` `parameters` has a unicode string as one of its values and it produces the error while coercing it to `str` type.

I've tried to set `convert_unicode=True` setting on engine and column, but without success.

So what is a good way to handle unicode in SQLAlchemy?

### UPDATE

This is some details about my setup:

**Table:**

```
                                    Table "public.documents"
   Column   |           Type           |                       Modifiers                        
------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('documents_id_seq'::regclass)
 sha256     | text                     | not null
 url        | text                     | 
 source     | text                     | not null
 downloaded | timestamp with time zone | not null
 tags       | json                     | not null
Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "documents_sha256_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (sha256)
```

**ORM model:**

```
class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'documents'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    sha256 = Column(TEXT(convert_unicode=True), nullable=False, unique=True)
    url = Column(TEXT(convert_unicode=True))
    source = Column(TEXT(convert_unicode=True), nullable=False)
    downloaded = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    tags = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
```

**SQLAlchemy settngs:**

```
ENGINE = create_engine('postgresql://me:secret@localhost/my_db',
                       encoding='utf8', convert_unicode=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=ENGINE)
```

And the code that produces the error is just creaes a session, instantiates a `Document` object and saves it with the `source`field`with`unicode` strign assigned to it.

### UPDATE #2

Check [this](https://github.com/AndrewPashkin/sqlalchemy_pg_unicode_save_fail) repo - it has automated Vagrant/Ansible setup, and it reproduces this bug.

Comment: What is the column type for the ORM class and the underlying table?  Make sure they are string type and not binary type.

Comment: @metatoaster I have a `TEXT` type.

Comment: What about the type of backend (sqlite, MySQL?), the actual table schema in the database, and the relevant code that defined the ORM class(es)?

Comment: @metatoaster Check the update in main text please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$ sudo grep client_encoding /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
client_encoding            = sql_ascii
```

That causes psycopg2 to default to ASCII:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> psycopg2.connect('dbname=dev_db user=dev').encoding
'SQLASCII'
```

... which effectively shuts off psycopg2's ability to handle Unicode.

You can either fix this in postgresql.conf:

```
client_encoding = utf8
```

(and then `sudo invoke-rc.d postgresql reload`), or you can specify the encoding explicitly when you create the engine:

```
self._conn = create_engine(src, client_encoding='utf8')
```

I recommend the former, because the early nineties are long gone. : )

Comment: Thanks a lot! What do you mean by "early nineties"? What is bad in defining client encoding in application side? I think its is actually more intuitive - if application assumes that cleint encoding is `utf8` - then it is more logical to put is somwhere in application.

Comment: And by the way - do you know, why if change client_encoding in Postgres config to ascii and execute `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;` in `psql` - it outputs `UTF8`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with setting client encoding explicitly on the application side. What I meant was that the *default* `client_encoding` (the one in the server) should be UTF-8. (Default encodings almost everywhere should be UTF-8.) So it would have been more precise to say I recommend *at least* the former. : )

Comment: As for the psql question, psql explicitly requests a client_encoding when it connects. From `man psql`: “If at least one of standard input or standard output are a terminal, then psql sets the client encoding to “auto”, which will detect the appropriate client encoding from the locale settings (LC_CTYPE environment variable on Unix systems).”

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your issue (also you didn't include examples on how you are actually adding your items into the database, fault might be there).  However, I encourage you to test your code in complete isolation with the rest of your system to see whether what you want to do actually works without the interference of your other code.  I created this file solely to test out whether what you wanted to do works, and the main method inserted the relevant object as a row into the database.

```
# encoding: utf-8

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, Float, Text
from sqlalchemy import Column, INTEGER, TEXT
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Demo(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'demo'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    key = Column(TEXT(convert_unicode=True))
    value = Column(TEXT(convert_unicode=True))


class Backend(object):

    def __init__(self, src=None):
        if not src:
            src = 'sqlite://'

        self._conn = create_engine(src)
        self._metadata = MetaData()
        self._metadata.reflect(bind=self._conn)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self._conn)
        self._sessions = sessionmaker(bind=self._conn)

    def session(self):
        return self._sessions()


def main():
    backend = Backend('postgresql://postgres@localhost/test')
    s = backend.session()
    obj = Demo()
    obj.key = 'test'
    obj.value = u'–test–'
    s.add(obj)
    s.commit()
    return backend
```

Running this inside the interpreter:

```
>>> b = main()
>>> s = b.session()
>>> s.query(Demo).get(1).value
u'\u2013test\u2013'
```

And within psql:

```
postgres=# \c test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# select * from demo;
 id | key  | value  
----+------+--------
  1 | test | –test–
(1 row)
```

Sorry that I wasn't able to really help you, but I hope this will point you (or someone else) into figuring out why your code is getting unicode decoding error.  Versions of software I used are python-2.7.7, sqlalchemy-0.9.6, psycopg2-2.5.3, postgresql-9.3.4.

Comment: Actually your topic hepled me - I executed your script in my virtualenv and it gives me `UnicodeEncodeError` - just hte same as I wrote in the main text. Thanks a lot for the complete test case!

Comment: Check this [repo](https://github.com/AndrewPashkin/sqlalchemy_pg_unicode_save_fail) - it has automated Vagrant/Ansible setup, and it reproduces my bug.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your error. I can provide a few tips regarding unicode handling with SQLAlchemy that may or may not help:

- Instead of using `convert_unicode` just use the sqlalchemy.types.Unicode() column type. That will always do the right thing.
- You are assigning a str instance (`'key'`) to the `key` column, even though you used `convert_unicode=True`. You will either want to assign a unicode value, or use a non-unicode code column type.
- Always check if the encoding for your PostgreSQL database is set correctly to UTF-8.
- Normally you do not need the `encoding` and `convert_unicode` parameters for create_engine.

Comment: What do you mean, can't reproduce? Did you used my Vagrant setup?